# typescript Object is possibly undefined in similar cases

Tags: typescript

```js
type Person = {
    account?: {
        money: number
    }
}

const person: Person = {}

// case1 - this is not error
if (person.account?.money === 0) {
    console.log("I have no money");
}

// case2 - Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532)
if (person.account?.money > 0) {
    console.log("I have money!!");
}
```

Why does not typescript show error on case 1, but only case 2?
What's difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do mathematical comparisons (`<`,`>`, `<=`, `>=`) with optional variables, it makes no sense and Typescript is reminding you to specify what to do in the situation.

```
> undefined < 1
  // false
> undefined > 1
  // false
```

This rule is enabled by the [strictNullChecks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) option.

Comment: Thanks, How about this?  
`if (person.account?.money > 0) {
    console.log(person.account.money); => // Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532)  why??
}` I think `person.account` cannot be undefined

Comment: If the compiler is complaining, a field has to be optional,  maybe `money` is ?

Comment: I think that if `person.account?.money > 0` is ture, then we can sure that `person.account` is never `undefined`. Check this [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBQKgEMBjE5AV1WAH4AuHfQ5gWzQhAdQpYCMEmBAL64RucqkTAokJGgZw56LNjEB6NVBJFEEAIxQAtFGAALAJaIolqKmTSE8ZPFzmAZlAAUslKgB0pORUtH5sqByYGFgADACUjMwSKAA2EH7JyADm3gi+AWSU1DSh7CCxANyiuLgaWjoQAExGUADyvABWECTSNmDIiIjmvMkgUADkVAAmEG7m4ZNjfp4NAKwAzA2xrh45SvlBRSXhowB8UHEJhLVmNjZEySitHV09Vn0DQyPjUzNzEAtLVYbLbMWoAd1Moxo1g8PjQ+0KITCETO0WsVmAFHgEAANCZTBB0GDoNp0IgsdA4f5Aoj0bYIAA3BBQH6zeZ+QRaNApNIZbJUhHBI4cCqiIA) please!

Comment: remove the `> 0` part and you have you fix. First check for `person.account` to be defined.